# VS Remote build - Visual studio resolves directory incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, cross-platform

I had a functional remote build.  Got a new Windows PC.  Installed VS, set up same environment variables, pulled same source code from svn, pointed VS at the same remote machine using the same remote account.

Basic error is the windows (local) path is being concatenated to the linux (remote) one:

```
1>g++ : error : /home/tyler/vsBuildRoot/trunk/CoreTech/ThirdPartyTools/Encryption/Rijndael/Project/Linux/S/buildroot/CoreTech/ThirdPartyTools/Encryption/Rijndael/Project/Linux/../../Source/Rijndael.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone provide any hints as to how these inputs might result in the given outputs?

```
1>Target "ResolveRemoteDir" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets":
1>  Using "ResolveRemoteDir" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Microsoft.Build.Linux.Tasks.dll".
1>  Task "ResolveRemoteDir"
1>    Task Parameter:RemoteProjectDir=/home/tyler/vsBuildRoot/trunk/CoreTech/ThirdPartyTools/Encryption/Rijndael/Project/Linux/
1>    Task Parameter:RemoteTarget=802522027;192.168.1.107 (username=, port=22, authentication=PrivateKey)
1>    Task Parameter:ProjectDir=S:\buildroot\CoreTech\ThirdPartyTools\Encryption\Rijndael\Project\Linux\
1>    Task Parameter:IntermediateDir=../../Build/Rijndael/Linux/LIB/Release/x64/
1>    Task Parameter:RemoteProjectDirFile=../../Build/Rijndael/Linux/LIB/Release/x64/802522027.RemoteProjectDirFile.tlog
1>    Task Parameter:RequireRemoteConnection=True
1>    Output Property: _ResolvedRemoteProjectDir=/home/tyler/vsBuildRoot/trunk/CoreTech/ThirdPartyTools/Encryption/Rijndael/Project/Linux/S/buildroot/CoreTech/ThirdPartyTools/Encryption/Rijndael/Project/Linux
1>  Done executing task "ResolveRemoteDir".
```

Some tasks correctly generate `_ResolvedRemoteProjectDir`, some do not.  The key inputs always seem to be the same.  I should note that this happens for multiple projects...which are clearly inheriting something different.  I just can't figure out what.

I am very stumped.

Worth noting, that `s:` is a virtual drive that is sometimes referenced through various variables in our build.  The physical drive *never* is.  On **this** computer, that maps to `c:\S_Drive`.  If I open the solution from there, the remote directory does change to `c:\S_Drive`

Comment: Hi friend, have you checked whether the project structure in local machine is the same as the structure in remote Linux machine? It seems to be a similar issue like [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a69b656-9c8d-4d29-acbb-aeae074b3535/visual-studio-2019-for-linux-g-no-such-file-or-directory?forum=vcgeneral), and has been reported to the [product team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/567519/file-directory-disappear-when-build-the-linux-c-pr.html) and filed with bug tag.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Yeah, the structure was the same.  `s:\buildroot` / `/home/tyler/vsBuildRoot/trunk` were both pulled from the same source control repository (and were clean pulls).  My home directory got deleted by VS trying to resolve this.  I switched the build to a sandboxed account, naturally, and this issue has gone away, along with a long-standing issue of Project->Clean deleting files it shouldn't.  Fairly baffling. (fyi: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/653601/remote-directory-resolution-incorrect.html)

Comment: Weird...Actually only fixed for the one project...rest of the solution still has concat issue...so bizarre.